When does the tRAMP timing begin for Cyclone 5 Power Supplies?
I am currently designing a power supply setup for a Cyclone 5 FPGA.
In the datasheet, it is stated that if power supplies do not reach operating conditions within the maximum tRAMP time allowed (100ms in my scenario with standard POR delay) the device will remain tri-stated.
My question is, does the tRAMP spec apply to each different supply individually? Or, does it apply to each supply as a whole? e.g. Can I switch on the Vcc supply (ramps within say 10ms) and then wait a few seconds and switch on another supply? Or, must they all turn on within 100ms after the first supply begins to ramp?
The image below is an extract from the datasheet, Figure 10-4 of the Cyclone V Handbook Volume 1, and seems to imply they can be timed individually?


The information is about as clear as mud on this, but from reading the device datasheet specifications, and the power-up sequencing section of the handbook, it is my understanding that the tramp specification applies each power supply rail individually. i.e. the first power supply must rise from 0-100% in  tramp, as must the second, and so on. This is what is inferred by the diagram presented (tramp is drawn from the start of the last power supply rail to the end of it).

However, I'm actually not so sure on the above. Based on reading the intel community forums, it does in fact appear that tramp is the total time within which all power supplies must have reached their nominal level - i.e. the time from the first power supply beginning to ramp to to the time when the last power supply has finished powering up.
From this thread, the answer by "Rahul_S_Intel1 (Employee)" indicates:

Do you mean that the sum of all power rails' t_ramp should be within 50us-50ms?
Yes

However that implies that the person who answered it understood the question, of which there is no guarantee. I would be tempted to ask your question there and push them until you get an unambiguous answer and hopefully convince them to update the datasheet to be crystal clear on this.

In terms of powering the supplies in sequence, there are two power supply groups for the Cyclone V devices as shown in following figure (Figure 10-3 of the datasheet linked in the question):

According to the power-up sequencing section of the device handbook, group 1 must be powered up and reach 80% of the full rail voltage before group 2 is powered up.
Furthermore, from the following support article there is no restriction on the order in which any of the group 2 power rails can be powered up - so for example VCCA could come up before VCCIO. The only recommendation there is that VCCIO and VCCPD are powered up simultaneously.
The power-on-reset circuitry monitors the power rails individually, holding the device in reset until all supplies have reached 80% (POR trip level) then waits for a set timeout (POR delay). So the device won't start configuring until all rails are powered up.

Yes, the information in the datasheet regarding this stuff is very poor. Especially considering most designs may need four or five different power supplies, each with their own ramp timings. Thank you for the suggestion, I will post on Intel's forums directly.

The Hot-Socketing Feature section of the Cyclone V Handbook Volume 1 contains the following which I think is relevant to the question:

Cyclone V devices support hot socketing—also known as hot plug-in or hot swap. The hot-socketing circuitry monitors the VCCIO, VCCPD, and VCC power supplies and all VCCIO and VCCPD
banks.
You can power up or power down these power supplies in any sequence.
During the hot-socketing operation, the I/O pin capacitance is less than 15 pF and the clock pin capacitance is less than 20 pF.
The hot-socketing capability removes some of the difficulty that designers face when using the Cyclone V devices on PCBs that contain a mixture of devices with different voltage requirements.
The hot-socketing capability in Cyclone V devices provides the following advantages:

You can drive signals into the I/O, dedicated input, and dedicated clock pins before or during power up or power down without damaging the device. External input signals to the I/O pins of the unpowered device will not power the power supplies through internal paths within the device.
The output buffers are tri-stated during system power up or power down. Because the Cyclone V device does not drive signals out before or during power up, the device does not affect the other operating buses.
You can insert or remove a Cyclone V device from a powered-up system board without damaging or interfering with the system board's operation. This capability allows you to avoid sinking current through the device signal pins to the device power supply, which can create a direct connection to
GND that causes power supply failures.
During hot socketing, Cyclone V devices are immune to latch up that can occur when a device is hot-socketed into an active system.


Given the above it looks like the tRAMP specification does apply to each different supply individually.
However, it does appear to partially conflict with the other answer (which appeared while I was typing this).

I have recieved a reply from an Intel support officer. The timing is individual to each power supply. i.e. Each supply has 100ms to reach operating conditions (with standard POR).
Please see here: https://community.intel.com/t5/Programmable-Devices/When-does-the-tRAMP-timing-begin-for-Cyclone-5-Power-Supplies/m-p/1593683/emcs_t/S2h8ZW1haWx8dG9waWNfc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9ufExWTFNXRU1CUjRTS1hWfDE1OTM2ODN8U1VCU0NSSVBUSU9OU3xoSw#M95830
Kind regards,
